# dim(nul(A)) = dim(nul(A^T))?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I am currently trying to prove that the union of an orthogonal subspace $W$ and its orthogonal complement $W^\perp$ span $\Bbb R^n$. In order to do this, I am trying to use the Rank-Nullity theorem.

If $A$ is a matrix with its columns being the basis of $W$, then I know $ColA = W$. I also know $(colA)^\perp = W^\perp = nul(A^T)$.

The only thing I'm stuck on is $\dim(nul(A)) = \dim(nul(A^T))$? If this is the case, then by the Rank-Nullity theorem $\dim(nul(A)) + \dim(col(A)) = \dim(\Bbb R^n) \iff \dim(W^T) + \dim(W) = \dim(R^n)$.

Is it right in general to assume $\dim(nul(A)) = \dim(nul(A^T))$? If not, how should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Yes. Row rank equals column rank, i.e. $\dim Col A^T = \dim Col A$. Now apply the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Not generally. The rank of $A$ equals the rank of $A^T$. If $A$ is $m\times n$, then the rank-nullity theorem applied to $A$ gives
$$
n=\dim\operatorname{nul}(A)+\operatorname{rk}(A)
$$
and applied to $A^T$ it gives
$$
m=\dim\operatorname{nul}(A^T)+\operatorname{rk}(A^T)
$$
By subtraction, in general you can say that
$$
n+\dim\operatorname{nul}(A^T)=m+\dim\operatorname{nul}(A)
$$
and, when $m=n$, which is your case,
$$
\dim\operatorname{nul}(A)=\dim\operatorname{nul}(A^T)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Well... $\dim(Nul(A^T))=\dim (colA)^\perp=n-\dim(col(A))=\dim(nul(A))$.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh right on. Thanks!